# specialization on const member function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, boost, specialization, pointer-to-member

I am trying to specialize some utility code on const member functions, but have problems to get a simple test-case to work.
To simplify the work i am utilizing *Boost.FunctionTypes* and its [`components<FunctionType>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/decomposition.html#boost_functiontypes.reference.decomposition.components) template - a *MPL sequence* which should [`contain`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/contains.html) the tag [`const_qualified`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/tag_types.html#boost_functiontypes.reference.tag_types.const_qualified) for const member functions.

But using the test-code below, the specialization on const member functions fails. Does anybody know how to make it work?

The test-code prints out (using VC8 and boost 1.40):

> non-const
>   non-const

Expected output is:

> non-const
>   const

The test-code itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/function_type.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>

namespace ft  = boost::function_types;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

template<typename F>
struct select 
{    
    template<bool IsConst /* =false */>
    struct helper {
        static void f() { std::cout << "non-const" << std::endl; }  
    };

    template<>
    struct helper</* IsConst= */ true> {
        static void f() { std::cout << "const" << std::endl; }  
    };

    typedef ft::components<F> components;
    typedef typename mpl::contains<components, ft::const_qualified>::type const_qualified;
    typedef helper<const_qualified::value> result;
};

typedef boost::function<void (void)> Functor;

template<typename MF>
Functor f(MF f)
{
    return boost::bind(&select<MF>::result::f);
}

class C 
{
public:
    void f1() {}
    void f2() const {}
};

int main()
{
    f(&C::f1)(); // prints "non-const" as expected
    f(&C::f2)(); // prints "non-const", expected "const"
}
```

Comment: While i found an alternative approach, i'd still be happy to accept a tested solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While its still unclear to me why the approach via `function_types::components<>` doesn't work, i realized that there is a simpler approach with *Boost.FunctionTypes* to specialize on const member functions:
The classification meta functions like [`is_member_function_pointer<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/classification.html#boost_functiontypes.reference.classification.is_member_function_pointer) optionally take a *tag* parameter ...

```
template<typename F>
struct select 
{    
    /* ... helper-struct as before */

    typedef ft::is_member_function_pointer<F, ft::const_qualified> const_qualified;
    typedef helper<const_qualified::value> result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, but shouldn't

```
typedef mpl::contains<components, ft::const_qualified> const_qualified;
```

be

```
typedef typename mpl::contains<components::type, ft::const_qualified>::type const_qualified;
```

Comment: I saw your edit there, but your components typedef also needs ::type or like I did in the post.

Comment: the ::type is like calling the meta function and getting the result. If you dont do that, it use the meta function itself.

Comment: Also doesn't make a difference.